# Scala compiler jar search order

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Is there anything that specifies in what order the Scala compiler searches through jar files?

I ran into a situation where one project I'm working on included three libraries that all included different versions of the same classes.  SBT and Intellij got different results so I believe they are searching the jars in different orders.  Does anyone know what order either of them uses?

I tried a google search, but that didn't help.

Comment: It should work in the order the jars appear in the classpath, but the classpath order can be different in SBT and IntelliJ IDEA due to bugs or other reasons specific to the way the IDE introspects the dependencies.

Comment: This is unspecified AFAIK: you should not rely on classpath order. If you have multiple versions of the same class in the classpath, you're gonna have trouble. At runtime, from one machine to another, there won't be any guarantee the order is the same. Get rid of the classes you don't want in the first place (exclusion from SBT, shading, whatever technique fits you best).